# Mirror from GitHub to git.kernel.org (e.g. not to GitLab instance)

Tags: git, github

I would like to mirror my repository on GitHub to git.kernel.org (normal gitolite based git hosting on linux server, not GitLab instance). Therefore I cannot use [GitLab feature repository mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/).

I also cannot use any service on git.kernel.org (and I don't want to setup any cron on any VPS, thus I rely on GitHub features. Is there such feature? I haven't found anything.

Comment: IMO the question is off topic here, but the GitHub Actions should be a good start: https://github.com/marketplace?category=&type=actions&verification=&query=mirror